# Extracting Non-Zero Data with column name from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like
[image]

Here I want to extract only the non-zero value (i.e 1) with column name
so the output will be:
[image]

I have replace the value 1 with the column name but was unable to remove other values and change its structure.

```
new_df = df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
```

Comment: This is not the exact answer to the question i have asked it will give the concatenated value like in first row the value will be 'worldus-newssociety'. I want to write the value as separate value in separate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#read the columns
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x!=0].tolist(),axis=1)
#maximum number of entries
max_cols=new_df.apply(len).max()
#create a new dataframe and pad the entries for missing values
new_df=pd.DataFrame(new_df.apply(lambda x: x+['']*(max_cols-len(x))).to_dict()).transpose()
#write to csv
new_df.to_csv('new_csv.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much if you can also tell to export it to csv as seperate column as above it will be easier for others also, and your answer will be complete. I have done it but it is exported as object.```new_df.to_csv('new.csv')```

Comment: I edited the answer. It should give you what you want now.

Comment: There is an error now ```arrays must all be same length```

Comment: @SujilDevkota try the updated solution

Comment: Great, it works thank you so much for your effort.